# IntentService onHandleEvent( ) not starting

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, intentservice

I want some methods to execute when I click on Notification Action Button.
I have searched on this site, but everything seems to be in order and my IntentService is not being called.

My Action-Button Intent

```
    Intent off = new Intent();
    off.setAction("action");
    off.putExtra("test", "off");
    PendingIntent pOff = PendingIntent.getService(context, 22, off, 0);
```

Notification Builder

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(/**/)
            .setContentTitle(/**/)
            .setContentText(/**/)
            .addAction(/**/, "Off", pOff)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Intent Service Class

```
public class NotificationServiceClass extends IntentService {

public NotificationServiceClass(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public NotificationServiceClass () {
    super("NotificationServiceClass");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("test", "onHandle");
    if (intent.getAction().equals("action")) {
        Log.i("test", "action");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Log.i("test", "onHandleBundleNotNull");
            if (bundle.containsKey("test")) {
                Log.i("test", bundle.getString("test"));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

XML Declaration for Service class

```
    <service
        android:name=".Manager.NotificationServiceClass"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Intents and Intent Filters training](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), the Intent you've built is an implicit Intent:

> Implicit intents do not name a specific component, but instead declare a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app to handle it. For example, if you want to show the user a location on a map, you can use an implicit intent to request that another capable app show a specified location on a map.

What you actually want is an explicit intent: one that specifies the component to start by name as per the note on the same page:

> Note: When starting a Service, you should **always specify the component name.** Otherwise, you cannot be certain what service will respond to the intent, and the user cannot see which service starts.

When constructing your Intent, you should use

```
// Note how you explicitly name the class to use
Intent off = new Intent(context, NotificationServiceClass.class);
off.setAction("action");
off.putExtra("test", "off");
PendingIntent pOff = PendingIntent.getService(context, 22, off, 0);
```

Comment: That was a really silly mistake.
Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your code, I do not see you telling the PendingIntent what class to use for your service.

You should add:

```
off.setClass(this, NotificationServiceClass.class);
```

Otherwise the PendingIntent has nothing to do.